# \otimes with upper and lower quadrants "removed"

Tags: symbols

Looking for a way to draw a slightly tidier version of the following, as a math operator akin to $\otimes$:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\center Like this only with upper and lower quadrants removed: \\
\center \Huge$\otimes$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the record:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too, like @egreg, am inclined toward a solution that draws the required symbol by hand.  With the help of the subroutines provided by the `halloweenmath` package (which is entirely concerned with drawing math symbols using `pict2e` facilities), we can provide a full answer that features:

- a binary operator named `\curvetie`;
- a corresponding “large” operator named `\bigcurvetie`;
- support for the `bold` math version.

This answer can also serve as an example of how to augment the `halloweenmath` package with the addition of custom symbols.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

% The "halloweenmath" package supplies some useful suroutines and also loads 
% the "amsmath" package:
\usepackage{halloweenmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@Roly@large@curvetie[1]{%
  \begin{@HwM@bigop@picture}\displaystyle \textfont {6}{-3}%
    \linethickness{#1\@HwM@thickness@units@for \textfont}%
    \moveto(0,0)
    \circlearc{0}{0}{3}{135}{225}%
    \circlearc{0}{0}{3}{45}{-45}
    \closepath
    \strokepath
  \end{@HwM@bigop@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@Large@Curvetie{%
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses \@Roly@large@curvetie
        {{}}%
        {{1.8}}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@small@curvetie[3]{%
  \begin{@HwM@bigop@picture}#1#2{4}{-2}%
    \linethickness{#3\@HwM@thickness@units@for #2}%
    \moveto(0,0)
    \circlearc{0}{0}{2}{135}{225}%
    \circlearc{0}{0}{2}{45}{-45}
    \closepath
    \strokepath
  \end{@HwM@bigop@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@Small@Curvetie[2]{%
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses{\@Roly@small@curvetie #1#2}%
        {{}}%
        {{1.6}}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@binop@curvetie[3]{%
  \begin{@HwM@oplus@picture}#1#2{2.8284271}{-1.4142135}%
    \linethickness{#3\@HwM@thickness@units@for #2}%
    \moveto(0,0)
    \circlearc{0}{0}{1.4142135}{135}{225}%
    \circlearc{0}{0}{1.4142135}{45}{-45}
    \closepath
    \strokepath
  \end{@HwM@oplus@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@Binop@Curvetie[2]{%
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses{\@Roly@binop@curvetie #1#2}%
        {{}}%
        {{1.5}}%
}
\newcommand*\curvetie{%
  \DOTSB
  \@HwM@general@binary@operation \@Roly@Binop@Curvetie
}
\newcommand*\bigcurvetie{%
  \DOTSB
  \@HwM@general@large@operator \@Roly@Large@Curvetie \@Roly@Small@Curvetie
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In-line:
\( \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \).
And in display:
\[ \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \]

Now repeat in boldface type.

\begingroup

\bfseries\boldmath

In-line:
\( \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \).
And in display:
\[ \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

---

**Edit:** I’d like to add a different version of the same code, with theonly difference that the thickness of the strokes has been adjusted to mimic more closely that of the `\`[`big`]`otimes` symbols.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

% The "halloweenmath" package supplies some useful suroutines and also loads 
% the "amsmath" package:
\usepackage{halloweenmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@Roly@large@curvetie[1]{%
  \begin{@HwM@bigop@picture}\displaystyle \textfont {6}{-3}%
    \linethickness{#1\@HwM@thickness@units@for \textfont}%
    \moveto(0,0)
    \circlearc{0}{0}{3}{135}{225}%
    \circlearc{0}{0}{3}{45}{-45}
    \closepath
    \strokepath
  \end{@HwM@bigop@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@Large@Curvetie{%
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses \@Roly@large@curvetie
        {{2.2}}% governs thickness for "normal" math version
        {{3}}%   governs thickness for "bold" math version
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@small@curvetie[3]{%
  \begin{@HwM@bigop@picture}#1#2{4}{-2}%
    \linethickness{#3\@HwM@thickness@units@for #2}%
    \moveto(0,0)
    \circlearc{0}{0}{2}{135}{225}%
    \circlearc{0}{0}{2}{45}{-45}
    \closepath
    \strokepath
  \end{@HwM@bigop@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@Small@Curvetie[2]{%
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses{\@Roly@small@curvetie #1#2}%
        {{1,8}}% normal
        {{2.2}}% bold
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@binop@curvetie[3]{%
  \begin{@HwM@oplus@picture}#1#2{2.8284271}{-1.4142135}%
    \linethickness{#3\@HwM@thickness@units@for #2}%
    \moveto(0,0)
    \circlearc{0}{0}{1.4142135}{135}{225}%
    \circlearc{0}{0}{1.4142135}{45}{-45}
    \closepath
    \strokepath
  \end{@HwM@oplus@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@Roly@Binop@Curvetie[2]{%
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses{\@Roly@binop@curvetie #1#2}%
        {{.8}}%  normal
        {{1.3}}% bold
}
\newcommand*\curvetie{%
  \DOTSB
  \@HwM@general@binary@operation \@Roly@Binop@Curvetie
}
\newcommand*\bigcurvetie{%
  \DOTSB
  \@HwM@general@large@operator \@Roly@Large@Curvetie \@Roly@Small@Curvetie
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In-line:
\( \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \).
And in display:
\[ \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \]

Now repeat in boldface type.

\begingroup

\bfseries\boldmath

In-line:
\( \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \).
And in display:
\[ \bigcurvetie_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} = X_{1}\curvetie\dots\curvetie X_{n} \]

\endgroup

Let us compare the thickness of the strokes:
\( {\bigotimes}{\bigcurvetie} \),
and \( {\otimes}{\curvetie} \).
{\bfseries\boldmath And in bold:
\( {\bigotimes}{\bigcurvetie}\ {\otimes}{\curvetie} \).}
Displayed:
\[ {\bigotimes}{\bigcurvetie} \]

\end{document}
```

The corresponding output follows:

[image: Output with thicker strokes]

Comment: Wow. Love the support for bold math. Will try it today.

Comment: I've accepted this answer. Rendering-wise, it's a slight improvement over @egreg's (otherwise excellent) solution, and `\bigcurvetie` is a useful complement. Thanks. (I ended up having to scale by 0.8, but I can live with that.)

Comment: @Roly: It’s very simple (if you know which parameter you have to tweak, of course!) to adjust the size of the symbols and/or the thickness of the strokes.  Would you prefer a slightly smaller symbol?  Or heavier strokes?  Please ask… :-)  P.S. I’ll see if I can add some explanation during the next weekend.

Answer (score 6):

With `pict2e`; perhaps not perfect at large sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\arcbowtie}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\arc@bow@tie\relax}}
\newcommand{\arc@bow@tie}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\otimes$}%
    \sbox\tw@{$\m@th\mkern1mu$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
    \linethickness{.4\wd\tw@}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \polyline(0.7878,0.7878)(0.2122,0.2122)
    \polyline(0.2122,0.7878)(0.7878,0.2122)
    \put(0.5,0.5){\arc[-46,46]{0.4}}
    \put(0.5,0.5){\arc[134,226]{0.4}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\arcbowtie B_{\arcbowtie}$

$A\otimes B_{\otimes}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. I'll try this out today, along with the solution based on `halloweenmath`.

Answer (score 3):

This might suffice.  I use `\clipbox` to truncate the top/bottom quadrants.  I declare it a math operator* and scale it to the height of an `X` in the local math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,amsmath,scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*\otimesop{\scalerel*{\clipbox{0pt 1.10pt 0pt 1.04pt}{$\otimes$}}{X}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \otimesop_{i=1}^n x_i = 42
\]
\[
  \otimesop \textstyle \otimesop \scriptstyle \otimesop \scriptscriptstyle \otimesop
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

One drawback of the above approach is that it is always scaling a `\textstyle` version of `\otimes` to the required size.  Thus, at the smaller math styles, the line width looks a bit thin.  A more computationally intensive alternative is to use the `\otimes` from the proper math style (and scale it, as needed).  Compare the below result to the above image.

Additionally, instead of scaling the operator to the size of `X`, I here scale it to the vertical size of `\mathop{X}^a`, to exaggerate the `\displaystyle` size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,amsmath,scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*\otimesop{\scalerel*{\clipbox{%
  0pt \dimexpr0.7\LMpt+0.4pt\relax{} 0pt \dimexpr0.64\LMpt+0.4pt\relax}{%
  $\SavedStyle\otimes$}}{\mathop{X}^a}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \otimesop_{i=1}^n x_i = 42
\]
\[
  \textstyle\otimesop_{i}^n x_i = 42
\]
\[
  \scriptstyle\otimesop_{i}^n x_i = 42
\]
\[
  \scriptscriptstyle\otimesop_{i}^n x_i = 42
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good effort, thanks. Is there a way to do a fancier clipping to render the "corners" correctly, or would that require a whole different kind of solution?

Comment: @Roly Alas, with `\clipbox`, the clip will always be a horizontal or vertical cut across the whole glyph.  But let me think to an alternative approach.

Comment: Wondering if there's something fancy you can do with rotation...but I know nothing.

Comment: @Roly In this case, no.  That is because the `\clipbox` cuts across the whole glyph.  If I cut at an angle (via rotation), it will adversely lop off the far side of the `\oplus`.